# C++ references and transient objects

Tags: c++, reference

I am currently working on a particular embedded system (in C++), which doesn't have much memory in it. Hence, using new/delete is out of the question. I do have some of my memory management system set up, however, I am exploring some other ways to solve certain problems (not exactly related to memory management, but that is really not important here). While searching, a rather simple question popped up, still I am not 100% sure about the answer, so I'd like to hear from experts on this one.

My question in the end is actually about references in C++, as well as how exactly transient objects function.

```
class Obj
{
    // id is automatically set, starting from 1, step by 1
    public: const int id = ...;

        // other unrelated stuff in the class
};

class Test
{
    public: Obj& obj;
    public: Test(Obj&& o) : obj(o) { }
};

void test()
{
    Obj o1; // id is 1
    Obj o2; // id is 2

    Test t = Obj(); // [*] id of this transient obj is 3

    cout << t.obj.id << endl; // prints 3, as expected?
}
```

I know that rvalue references are lvalues (since they are named objects, and named objects are always lvalues), hence the Test class is okay and has no errors (compile errors). However, the transient object Obj() (marked with *), as far as I know, should be destroyed after ; on the same line, so the test object 't' afterwards should have an invalid reference to a destroyed object, if I am correct. And the 3 printing is actually unexpected behavior, yet accidental that it still has 3 written in it's memory location which I am accessing while printing it out. Is this what is actually happening, or is there something else that I am lacking to see/know? Isn't there some kind of mechanism to detect such situation and prolong/extend the lifetime of the object until the one referencing it is destroyed as well (in this example, prolong the lifetime of Obj() until the end of the function test(), when the 't' gets destroyed)?

Comment: *Is this what is actually happening, [...]?* Yep.  You just got "lucky" it worked.

Comment: Why the r-value reference as constructor parameter? Normal one would be absolutely fine in this case.

Comment: @Aconcagua I am always calling the constructor with an rvalue from the outside. I know this looks silly, and yes I could do all this with new and have a pointer instead of a reference, but I can't use new (I'm trying to avoid it as much as possible, so I'm searching for some other solutions).

Comment: @Vlladz I wasn't talking about pointers, just about references. `Test(Obj& o) : obj(o) { }` would just do the same – and that even existed long before r-value references...

Comment: @Aconcagua In that case I can't pass rvalues, only lvalues, and I'm always passing rvalues to the constructor. For eg. if I switch to your solution, I won't be able to pass Obj() which I actually need.

Comment: @Vlladz You yourself in your question discovered already that the temporary created by `Obj()` is gone after current expression being executed. So you are just creating a dangling reference! How can *that* be helpful in any way? If the ordinary reference prevents this, even better...

Comment: @Aconcagua I was actually trying to confirm that here, if this is a dangling reference, that's the point, and I have. The use-case I'm having here is an unusual one, hence why this is a bit fuzzy. I'm not saying that my code is the solution, I am just searching for one, and I have found something other, which is okay in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard name for what you call "transient object" is "temporary object".

> However, the transient object Obj() (marked with *), as far as I know, should be destroyed after ; on the same line, so the test object 't' afterwards should have an invalid reference to a destroyed object, if I am correct. And the 3 printing is actually unexpected behavior

You are correct. The reference is invalid. The behaviour is undefined.

Temporary lifetime extends until the end of the full expression. Except when it is bound to a reference and if the reference has a longer lifetime, in which case the lifetime is extended to the lifetime of the reference.

In this case, the temporary is bound to the reference that is the argument of the constructor, whose lifetime does not extend for longer than the full expression where the constructor is invoked.

---

> Isn't there some kind of mechanism to detect such situation and prolong/extend the lifetime of the object until the one referencing it is destroyed as well (in this example, prolong the lifetime of Obj() until the end of the function test(), when the 't' gets destroyed)?

Yes! That mechanism is class members. Unlike temporaries unrelated to an object, member objects live at least as long as the object that contains them.

```
struct Test
{
    Obj obj;
};

Test t{};
```

Comment: Thanks! Of course, the constructor argument, that makes a lot of sense! That one was bugging me obviously.
As for the class members, I forgot to mention, I do need somebody from outside to pass the argument to the class through a constructor (it's always an rvalue), however, I do not wish any copying/moving to be done with copy/move constructors whatsoever, so in that case, that's the reason why I used a reference instead of regular member.
Of course, you may be asking why do I need this, well all of this could be solved with a simple new & pointer, but as I said, I can't use new.

Answer (score 1):

Let me modify your example a little bit. I removed the `const` and added a destructor to `Obj`. As you can see, the object is destroyed. In your case, without a destructor, `id` is not overwritten, but you can't rely on that.

```
class Obj {
private:
    static int next;
public:
    int id;
    Obj() {
        id = next;
        ++next;
    }
    ~Obj() {
        id = 42;
    }
};
int Obj::next = 1;

class Test {
public:
    Obj& obj;
    Test(Obj&& o) : obj(o) { }
};

void test() {
    Obj o1; // id is 1
    Obj o2; // id is 2
    Test t = Obj(); // id is 3
    cout << t.obj.id << endl; // prints 42
}
```

**[edit]**

It would be better to add a copy constructor to `Obj` and modify `Test` to store a copy of a given const-referenced  object.

```
class Obj {
private:
    static int next;
public:
    int id;
    Obj() {
        id = next;
        ++next;
    }
    Obj(const Obj& x) {
        id = next;
        ++next;
    }
    ~Obj() {
        id = 42;
    }
};
int Obj::next = 1;

class Test {
public:
    Obj obj;
    Test(const Obj& o) : obj(o) {}
};

void test() {
    Obj o1; // id is 1
    Obj o2; // id is 2
    Test t = Obj(); // id is 3
    cout << t.obj.id << endl; // prints 4
}
```